# Accessing objects of other classes java

Tags: java

I want to access an object i created in a new class but it returns that the object " cannot be resolved".
thanks for anyone who helps:)

here is my code :

```
public class lion {

        int weight;
        int height;
        String color;
        double roardecibles;

            public void lioncolor() {
                System.out.println(color);
            }   

    }

public class blacklion {

          lion blackLion;{

     blackLion = new lion();


        blackLion.weight =4;
        blackLion.height =3;
        blackLion.color = "black";
        blackLion.roardecibles = 5.5;

        }
          }

public class zoo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        blackLion.lioncolor(); //here it dosent work//

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want `public class BlackLion extends Lion` ? Have a read up on inheritance in java

Comment: you can just read a few lines in any java tutorial for newcomers and to understand what's your problem. it is not a question stackoverflow orientates at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between an object and a class. Think of a class as a blueprint, that's what you did when you defined it in `public class blacklion`. But you didn't actually build something with the blueprint. To create an object you have to instantiate it, using the `new` keyword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    blacklion lion = new blacklion();
    lion.lioncolor(); //here it dosent work//

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to instantiate an Object of your class that you can then access from where u created it. If you want to access methods or variables of a class directly you want to declare those as public and static.

Answer (score 0):

Hey looks like you should check out this resource:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Specifically the section of how classes work:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   blackLion.lioncolor(); //here it dosent work//
}
```

needs an instance of the object in order to call the lioncolor() method